# why '!= 'and '== 'don't work in while or for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, while-loop

without the loop != and == work but if I put them into the loop they don't work

```
a = int(input())
while a != 'stop':
x = int(input())
y = str(input())
z = str(input())
if x == 'A':
    x = a
    if y == z:
        a = a + x
    elif y != z:
        a = a - x
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? What did you enter? What is the desired and observed result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude python cares about indents. Every single line that you want to loop through the while loop should be indented. Try indenting the code and try again

Comment: Thankyou all who upvoted this. Really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in any way but the wrong indentation may be the problem.

Comment: Currently, you've presented us with illegal Python code.  The line after a while statement has to be more indented.  Also, why do you think your code doesn't work?  How is it failing?

Answer (score 0):

the fix probably, Added indents:

```
a = int(input())
while a != 'stop':
   x = int(input())
   y = str(input())
   z = str(input())
   if x == 'A':
     x = a
     if y == z:
        a = a + x
     elif y != z:
        a = a - x
```